# What does it mean if fees are "burned" in the context of EIP-1559?

Tags: fees, eip-1559, burn

I am looking for a simple explanation of what burning "fees" means and implies in the context of EIP-1559.

Answer (score 2):

What they mean with burn is sending the ethereum to an address that has no private key or defunct address. As a result, the tokens are lost forever.

Comment: Thank you. But does this explanation also apply to burning ‘transaction fees’. I can see how you can burn ETH, but not how you can burn transaction fees.

Answer (score 1):

In EIP-1559, burning the Base Fee means that the Base Fee is not sent to anyone.  The Base Fee vanishes rather than being sent to the miner/validator.

In the [specification](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1559.md#specification) it looks like:

```
# miner only receives the priority fee; note that the base fee is not given to anyone (it is burned)

self.account(block.author).balance += gas_used * priority_fee_per_gas
```